# How to allow NULL value on foreign key on php

Tags: php, mysqli, many-to-many

Good day. I am seeking for help on what to do with the codes:
The PHP part:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

  $student = $_POST['student']; 
  $lecture = $_POST['lecture'];
  $room = $_POST['room'];

  $students = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE student='$student'");
  $lectures = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture='$lecture'");
  $rooms = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room='$room'");

  $student_row = mysqli_fetch_array($students);
  $lecture_row = mysqli_fetch_array($lectures);
  $room_row = mysqli_fetch_array($rooms);
```

What I want to do in this part is, if there is no entry on room input insert the value null in the room_id column in the reference table:

```
  if($student != $student_row['student']) {
    $addStudent = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO students (student) VALUES ('$student')");
    $studentID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
  }else{
    $studentID = $student_row['student_id'];
  };

  if($lecture != $lecture_row['lecture']) {
    $addLecture = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO lectures (lecture) VALUES ('$lecture')");
    $lectureID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
  }else{
    $lectureID = $lecture_row['lecture_id'];
  };

  if($room != $room_row['room']) {
    $addRoom = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO rooms (room) VALUES ('$room')");
    $roomID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
  }else{
    $roomID = $room_row['room_id'];
  };
```

I think this is the part that needs to be changed:

```
  $addClass = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO classes (student_id,lecture_id,room_id) VALUES ('$studentID','$lectureID','$roomID')");

  if($addClass){
    echo 'Success';
  }else{
    echo 'Error: '.mysqli_error($con);
  };
};
?>
```

The HTML part:

```
<html>
<title>Add Class</title>
<body>
  <form name="Add Class" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Student: <input type="text" name="student" />
    </br></br>
    Lecture: <input type="text" name="lecture" />
    </br></br>
    Room: <input type="text" name="room" />
    </br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Class">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the table is set as a foreign key, that means that ALWAYS there must be a relation between  both tables. If you want that kind of behavior you just can't use foreign keys.

Comment: How is it that if I manually add entry on phpmyadmin, I can set null values there? but when it comes to form. There is an error: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`classes`, CONSTRAINT `classes_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`room_id`))"

Comment: @MikeVelazco He can actually. A FOREIGN key can be NULL, though it cannot be anything else other than NULL or a valid value that satifies the constrain.

Comment: @EdisGolubich how can I make this work? It only succeed when all fields are filled up.

Comment: @Oween I posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can simply insert NULL as value. Like this:

```
if(empty($room))
  $room = "NULL";
```

right before the mysqli insert. Make sure you actually pass the string null not empty or 0.

Oh and you obviously need to make sure the column is not marked as `NOT NULL`